# Spring annotations not working in library jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

In a nutshell, we began with a single Spring MVC project. Call it proj1, so the package was `com.foo.proj1`. Later, we based a second project on the same codebase, so we then had `com.foo.proj1` and `com.foo.proj2`. We then refactored common code into a library, as in a `com.foo.lib` JAR to be used in both web apps. It's included as a regular Maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>foo-lib</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

The problem we're having is that `@Component` and `@Autowired` notations aren't working within the library code. Autowiring components that exist in the library JAR works fine in proj1 and proj2, it's internal uses of `@Autowired` within the library that result in null references.

I've done a lot of searching and reading trying to nail this down. It seems that Spring is not doing the component scanning in the library JAR as desired. The projects use XML configuration for the high-level configuration issues, and include:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo"/>
```

The library has a web.xml as follows (I omitted the enclosing web-app tag as stackoverflow didn't like the formatting):

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/application-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

The library application-config.xml (again omitting the outermost beans tag):

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo"/>
```

I've gathered that the component scanning (unfortunately) depends on more than just the base-package value. What Spring configuration does the library need, and how should it be referenced from the Spring MVC projects that use it?

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure about you context config ?

Comment: Does the library project have its own context configuration?

Comment: It does, I'll update the question with it...

Comment: Can you try to remove the application-context of your jar ? So you only have the one of your ear/war

Comment: I did try that at one point, and it does make sense to me that only the main app should contain config information. Essentially it should force the component scan then?

Comment: I had suspected that this had to do with setting up the spring context for the library jar. I've proceeded down that path, adding the context configuration XML to the jar's META-INF dir and referencing it from the app's application context via an import resource tag. I can see it get loaded in the log, but it didn't result in the annotations being processed. I'm going to open a question specific to that issue. Thanks to everyone that looked this over.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add that in your web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Which spring's version are you using ?